# Switching from back camera to front camera for video recording is not working

Tags: android, android-camera, video-recording, front-camera

Back camera is working fine but,when we switch from back to front camera ,it crashes(in case of video recording using MediaRecorder ).... it showing error which i show in log !!

[image]

Here is my code :

```
private void start_work()
 {
  if(recording)
  {


   Log.v("LOGTAG", "Recording Stopped");


  }
  else
  {
   recording = true;
   progress_relative_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   button_capture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   //show_icon();

   recorder.start();
   Log.v("LOGTAG", "Recording Started");


  }
 }
```

and for initialize i use

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();


 recorder.setOrientationHint(result) ;
  recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
  if(usecamera)
  {
   camera.unlock();
   recorder.setCamera(camera);

  }
  recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
  recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
  recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);
```

Comment: you need always release camera before switching

Comment: i release camera before switching,i use    if(camera != null)
       {
        camera.stopPreview(); // stop preview
        camera.release(); // release previous camera
       } before switching..

Comment: from the above code i can see only  if(previewRunning)
   {
    camera.stopPreview();
   }

Comment: i have also added        camera.release(); ..  i have use one more method for switching camera...there i have added        camera.release();

Comment: then you should create new instance of camera with front cam propery

Comment: i have try this too,but its not working ,i use   camera = getCameraInstance(front_or_back_camera); after that i refresh camera

Comment: put the edited code as well... full code

Comment: what is t.start(); ?

Comment: not related to this ,it was something else i use totally different from this

Comment: where u stopping recorder and releasing it

Comment: you know that recorder has a life cycle and you have to follow the life cycle

Comment: ya i know that and i can't post my whole code, and i m releasing recorder i told you previously..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some times device go in onPause state ,i just re initialize everything in onResume method of the activity and it works..!

Answer (score 2):

```
  if (camera != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("camera already initialized");
        }

        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();

        // Try to find a front-facing camera (e.g. for videoconferencing).
        int numCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCameras; i++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
           //this will be front or back depending on the requirement 
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                camera= Camera.open(i);
                break;
            }
        }
```

try adding this part of code

Comment: i am using the same----------------------   private Camera getCameraInstance(int type)
 {
  Camera c = null;
  int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
  {
   CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
   Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
   if(info.facing == type)
   {
    try
    {
     c = Camera.open(i); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
     // Camera is not available
     Util_Class.show_Toast("Camera not available.",getActivity());
    }
    break;
   }
  }
  return c;
 }

Comment: Now i have make some changes and it is working fine but problem exist for recording --MediaRecorder.start(); in case of front camera......it throw error on this line

Comment: code is almost same ,i just add  if(camera != null)
   {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    camera.lock();
    camera.release();
   }   camera.release was already there..                                                now i have error in recorder.start();

Comment: are you releasing the recorder ?

Comment: you cant have same recorder object for both front and back recording

Comment: not working.....i try by releasing recorder and then re initialize it but its not working

Comment: put that part of code also.. i am not able to understand with this code ..its a part of code.. and error is coming from somewhere else

Comment: thats what i am trying to say.. i am not finding any recorder object in the above code